# How to search for and print items in the input, python?

Tags: python, list

I just got into coding and have a query.
I'm writing a script for a chatbot named Sasha, however I am not able to find any method to solve the problem of not all words matching in a sentence.
Say, I want to ask it to check the date differently rather than just saying, 'date'. How would I go about doing that ?
Any help is appreciated.

```
Database =[

        ['hello sasha', 'hey there'],

        ['what is the date today', 'it is the 13th of October 2017'],

        ['name', 'my name is sasha'],

        ['weather', 'it is always sunny At Essex'],

        ]

while 1:
        variable = input("> ") 

        for i in range(4):
                if Database[i][0] == variable:
                        print (Database[i][1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'in' to check if something is in a list, like so: (in pseudocode)

```
list = ['the date is blah', 'the time is blah']

chat = input('What would you like to talk about')

if chat in ['date', 'what is the date', 'tell the date']:
  print(list[0])

elif chat in ['time', 'tell the time']:
  print(list[1])

etc.
```

You should consider learning about what dictionaries are, that would help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you could use dict to map input to answer

update:
add regex to match the input, but I think your question more like NLP question.

```
import re
Database ={

        'hello sasha': 'hey there',

        'what is the date today':'it is the 13th of October 2017',

        'name': 'my name is sasha',

        'weather': 'it is always sunny At Essex',

        }

while 1:
        variable = input("> ") 
        pattern= '(?:{})'.format(variable )
        for question, answer in Database.iteritems():
            if re.search(pattern, question):
                 print answer
```

output:

```
date
it is the 13th of October 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

A very rudimental answer would be to check for a word in the sentence:

```
while 1:
    variable = input("> ") 

    for i, word in enumerate(["hello", "date", "name", "weather"]):
        if word in input.split(" "):  # Gets all words from sentence 
            print(Database[i][1])


    in: 'blah blah blah blah date blah'
    out: 'it is the 13th of October 2017'
    in: "name"
    out: "my name is sasha"
```